# Closing an 'accordian' <div> but forcing a 'top' return

Tags: php, html, css

I have an 'accordion' embedded in a PHP while loop... the PHP pulls data from the DB to fill the panels-- this part works fine. Each panel loads and opens according to the label links as stated... all is OK to this point.

However, when the call link to close the panel is clicked, the page drops fully to the bottom of the 'html body', rather than returning back to the top of the 'html body' and showing the full 'accordion' as available.. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<div id="container">
<?php
// title heading
$seek_title=mysql_query("select title from lessons where id = $lesson_id");
$the_title=mysql_fetch_array($seek_title);
$lesson_title= $the_title[0];
echo '<h3>'.$lesson_title.'</h3>';
// count pages
$count_pages= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE lesson_id = '$lesson_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$page_count= mysql_num_rows($count_pages);?>
<a name="top"></a>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<?php      
for ($x=1; $x <= $page_count; $x++){
//SQL to pull title and content for the current page
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title, body FROM pages WHERE lesson_id = '$lesson_id' AND position = '$x' ") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$title = $row[0];
$content = $row[1];?>
<div class="panel panel-default" >
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title"><strong>
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $x; ?>"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $title; ?></a></strong></h3>
</div>
<div id="collapse<?php echo $x; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body" ><?php echo $content; ?>
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $x; ?>" ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Close</a><br/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the close tag to following:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordion"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Close</a><br/>
```

Note to the href. It should go to the top from now on.

Comment: The above solution did not work uniformly because of being inside a 'while loop' ... this was one of my original attempts.See below for Questioned solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was two-fold; first, above the id="container" I added:

```
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Then, at the 'close call' within the while-loop, I added this edit:

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Close</a></p>
```

Now, it returns to the page-load with the accordion closed and everything is at the top.  Thanks for the try.